# How to get Vue routes from the API call

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am building a dashboard site using [Laravel](http://laravel.com) and [Vue.js](http://vuejs.org).There are many people who are using my App. Some of them are admins, while others are normal users. In the left-side bar, there are many categories. For example in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAk6r.png) Components is only accessed by the admin.

The question is how to properly fetch routes (menu in this case) from the API call and populate them to my app, after the app is loaded already.. This is my JSON from the server

[image: my code]

Comment: Official way to do this is to use functional components: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components